# Order of QML entries

Tags: qgis, style, qml

In my styling file I have a `value map` with a certain order. But whenever I load it to `QGIS` the order changes. For example in my styling file I defined this.

```
<edittype widgetv2type="ValueMap" name="group">
      <widgetv2config fieldEditable="1" constraint="" labelOnTop="0" constraintDescription="" notNull="0">
        <value key="" value=""/>
        <value key="A" value="C"/>
        <value key="B" value="D"/>
        <value key="C" value="A"/>
        <value key="D" value="B"/>
      </widgetv2config>
    </edittype>
```

But if I load the (*.qml), my `value map` has another order. If I export it the code changes to this.

```
<edittype widgetv2type="ValueMap" name="group">
      <widgetv2config fieldEditable="1" constraint="" labelOnTop="0" constraintDescription="" notNull="0">
        <value key="" value=""/>
        <value key="A" value="A"/>
        <value key="B" value="B"/>
        <value key="C" value="C"/>
        <value key="D" value="D"/>
      </widgetv2config>
    </edittype>
```

Is this a bug or does QGIS automatically change the order to alphabetically?
QGIS version 2.18.14